# Evaluate the expression inside brackets

Tags: python, list

I was asked to define a function that takes in a list of the following format:

- `[2, "+", 5], 3, 5]`

and returns a list with the evaluated expression such as this one

- `[7, 3, 5]`

#### This is my code:

```
def evalExpr(lst):
    """
    parameters : lst of type lst:
    returns : evaluation of the expression inside brackets;
    """
    for i in lst:
        if len(lst[i]) == 3:
            for j in lst[i]:
                if lst[i][j]== "+":
                    lst[i] = lst[i][j-1] + lst[i][j+1]
    return lst

print(evalExpr([[2, "+", 5], 3, 5]))
```

#### And this is the error I'm getting:

```
<ipython-input-1-5c5345233e02> in evalExpr(lst)
      5     """
      6     for i in lst:
----> 7         if len(lst[i]) == 3:
      8             for j in lst[i]:
      9                 if lst[i][j]== "+":

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

What should I do in order to get the right output?

Comment: What doesn't work? Bad output? an error? Be specific, And post a Stackdump if you have it.

Comment: Hint: look at the for loop carefully and read its documentation.

Comment: Hint 2: In your code, `i` is not an index (neither is `j`).

Comment: This might be interesting for you: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: and outermost if statement should have an else clause

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I run your code this is the exception I get:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-1d51996f7143> in <module>
----> 1 evalExpr([[2, "+", 5], 3, 5])

<ipython-input-1-5c5345233e02> in evalExpr(lst)
      5     """
      6     for i in lst:
----> 7         if len(lst[i]) == 3:
      8             for j in lst[i]:
      9                 if lst[i][j]== "+":

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not list
```

The highlighted line shows that `i` is not an integer (it is probably a list object) and you are trying to use it as an index. If you want the indices you need to use in the for loop the Python `enumerate` function. Then you will be able to work in each iteration with the indices and also the current value at the same time.

Here is an example of how you can use this useful Python function:

```
def evalExpr(lst):
    """
    parameters : lst of type lst:
    returns : evaluation of the expression inside brackets;
    """
    for i, e in enumerate(lst): # i is the index and e the actual element in the iteration
        if isinstance(e, list) and len(e) == 3:
            lst[i] = eval(str(lst[i][0]) + lst[i][1] + str(lst[i][2]))
    return lst

new_list = evalExpr([[2, "+", 5], 3, 5, [2,'*', 4], [2,'**', 4]])

print(new_list)
```

If you execute this code you will see this result on the console:

```
[7, 3, 5, 8, 16]
```

Comment: thanks for the thorough explanation, I'm only curious about what does this part check for `if str(type(e)).find('list') > -1`?

Comment: @MisterTusk this is just checking if the type of the current element `type(e)` is a list. In fact this is quite clumsy; I have therefore updated the answer using now `isinstance(e, list)` which does the same thing and is much more elegant.